# backreference in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a input file with below contents:

```
India ;91;0,1684
India Mobile ;9174;0,1630
India Fix ;9122;0,3345
```

I want to append ";MOB" to the second line so that the output looks like below

```
India ;91;0,1684
India Mobile ;9174;0,1630;MOB
India Fix ;9122;0,3345
```

I wrote a perl script which tries to do this using regular expression:

```
open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die "Can't open data";
@lines = <FILE>;
close FILE;

foreach(@lines) {
    chomp;
    s/(.* Mobile .*)/$1;MOB/;
    print $_ . "\n";
}
```

But this produces the output like below:

```
India ;91;0,1684
;MOBa Mobile ;9174;0,1630
India Fix ;9122;0,3345
```

Can anybody please guide me what is that small little trick I am missing here?

Comment: Tip: `s/(.* Mobile .*)/$1;MOB/;` is more efficient as `s/( Mobile .*)/$1;MOB/;`

Comment: Tip: `s/( Mobile .*)/$1;MOB/;` is more efficient as `s/ Mobile .*\K/;MOB/;`, but it requires Perl 5.10+

Comment: Tip: I'd use the cleaner `$_. = ';MOB' if / Mobile /;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input data appears to have carriage returns `\r` in them.  Run `dos2unix` on your input, then run your script.  It should work as expected.

**Explanation:** your substitution works, but because your data has a carriage return, the output becomes `India Mobile ;9174;0,1630\r;MOB`.
The carriage return moves the cursor to the beginning of the line and it begins to over-type when displayed.  That's why your output line appears to be `;MOBa Mobile` - it's actually `India Mobile` over-typed with `;MOB`.

Comment: Added s/\r$//; before applying the real expression and works..  Thanks.

Comment: Just use `s/\s+\z//;` instead of `chomp; s/\r$//;`.

Comment: @ikegami - Or if you know you're dealing with Windows style line endings, set `$/ = "\r\n"` and let `chomp` take care of it.

Comment: That's far more fragile. It will fail if one of the lines doesn't have the CR. You could use `binmode($fh, ':crlf')`. Unfortunately, you can't pass that to `use open`.